# Entity Framework - Ignore "invalid column name" error and set default value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know this is far from optimal, but here goes: In our team, we develop against the same development database, which sometimes gives us some trouble. Most of our trouble comes from "Invalid column name" errors, which happens when someone else modifies the database entities, which means SQL statements such as `SELECT Id, Name FROM TableName` fails if `Name` no longer exists.

Obviously this is not optimal, and we are moving towards having our own local environments, but this is what we have at the moment. I know the error comes from the database, but it would be really nice, if it was possible to have a fallback of some kind. Something like:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public async Task DoStuff()
{
    var people = new List<Person>();
    
    try 
    {
        people = await _dbContext.Persons.Select(x => new Person
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if(e.Message.Contains("Invalid column name 'Name'")
        {
            people = await _dbContext.Persons.Select(x => new Person
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = default
                })
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Get the point? If the database cannot find the column `Name` anymore, it should still SELECT stuff, but set `Name` to the default value (or null). Is that something Entity Framework can do? I know that I might potentially experience more issues, but 99/100 times someone has made a change, this is the culprit.

Comment: Could you add a prebuild command to run `dotnet ef scaffold` and check if any of your models have changed? That would at least let you know that something has changed and needs addressed.

Comment: @AustinC That's a good idea, but unfortunately our application is quite a monolith (yes, we're changing) and running scaffold command takes too long at every compilation :(

Comment: You can use GetSchema to get the columns names to automate finding root cause.

Comment: We are getting a similar problem where we a testing a bit of new code against a database that doesn't have all the new schema rolled out to it yet. The code we want to run doesn't specifically need the new columns, but it just fails with a similar error because it detected a missing column. Be nice if we could do a quick temporary workaround to aid our testing.